# Multiple projects react-native android build error

Tags: android, react-native, facebook

Here are the android/build.gradle files contents of two different project.

**PROJECT 1**

```
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        supportLibVersion = "29.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.0.0"
        firebaseVersion = "17.3.4"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "20.2.1"
        firebaseBomVersion="20.2.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
        classpath ("com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**PROJECT 2**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.5.0'
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        androidXCore = "1.7.0"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

When I execute: react-native-android, I get the following error.

**PROJECT 1**

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6).
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-login.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
```

**PROJECT 2**

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[8.1).
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[8.1).
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/%5B8.1)/facebook-login-%5B8.1).pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/%5B8.1)/facebook-login-%5B8.1).pom'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:9.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:9.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/9.0/facebook-android-sdk-9.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/9.0/facebook-android-sdk-9.0.pom'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:9.0.+.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-fbsdk-next
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
```

Note that I checked the following solutions but none worked

- [react native - could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50384733/react-native-could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-classpath)
- [Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481942/failed-to-resolve-com-facebook-androidfacebook-android-sdk4-5)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55027644/react-native-run-android-could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-for-configuration-cl[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55027644/react-native-run-android-could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-for-configuration-cl%5B2%5D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like some of your android dependencies are in [Jcenter](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/jcenter) repository.

Unfortunately, Jcenter is [currently down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72116295/6418928).

You have two choice for now :

- Wait for jcenter to be up (It has been down for 4 days at the moment)
- Migrate to use something else. See:

  - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration
  - [Bitrise: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath' Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72115970/bitrise-could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-for-configuration-classpath-could-no/72116295#comment127434212_72116295)

Answer (score 0):

Like Gkueny said Jcenter seems to be down.

I followed this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/70899081/6828556 to get my React-Native project running again. The fix works by removing the jcenter() links from my build.gradle and replacing them with MavenCentral()